# CSS transition blurry background

Tags: css

I have an element with a background image that simply moves up and down using css transitions. At some points in the animation the image goes slightly blurry. The graphic is more pixel art so it's really noticeable.

Is there any way I can have a smooth animation without the edges going blurry?

Additionally, is there any way to make Firefox animations smoother?

UPDATE (ignore code below): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpMvzb

```
#elem {
  width: 152px;
  height: 68px;
  -webkit-animation-name: Floating;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-name: Floating;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes Floating {
    from {-webkit-transform:translateY(0); }
    50% {-webkit-transform:translateY(2px);}
    to {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);}   
}

@-moz-keyframes Floating {
    from {-moz-transform:translateY(0);}
    50% {-moz-transform:translateY(2px);}
    to {-moz-transform: translateY(0);}    
}
```

Comment: Did you try backface-visibility: hidden; ?

Comment: I have, yes. It makes no difference sadly.

Comment: could you please provide a working example, on codepen. I can then look into it.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpMvzb there you go, thank you.